# ClickOnce File will not associate on open from web browser download

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce program that associates with a given extension and that works fine if the file is located on the file system.  My problem comes in when this file is downloaded from a website.  I have a web handler that prompts the user to Click to download the file.  Upon clicking the link the user is presenter with an Open or Save Dialog.  If the user chooses Open the program will not launch.  If the user saves the file to their hard drive and then clicks the file the association will work.

Any advice on getting the association to work on the prompt when the user clicks Open or is a Save required?

-Edit : Tested this on both IE8 and Chrome with same result.

Comment: What's the file Extension? Have you changed it at all from the publish? Have you changed the associated association in windows?

Comment: The file extension is .aav (custom) and no I have not changed the associated association in windows.  I even un-installed the program and reinstalled.  The association works properly if the file exists on the system and not in this temporary state.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759850/clickonce-file-association,  please remove.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Not even close.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Internet Explorer does not have vision into the file associations set for ClickOnce. That's why clicking on it from Internet Explorer doesn't work, but saving it to disk and opening it in Windows does work.

I would bet the problem is one of security and administrative privileges, which ClickOnce applications do not have.

Comment: Is there a known setting that will allow you to give privileges to this?

Comment: Not that I know of. I will tell you how we handled this, though. We have a web page that has files we want to open with our application. Rather than having it download the files, we pass the URL for the file to the application as a query parameter. The application checks for the parameter. If it finds it, it downloads the file and opens it in the application. Our app is single instance, so we had to add some named pipes stuff to handle the case where the app is already open -- we write the URL to a file and ping the running app to check for it.