# Own filetype: get name of calling file

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I created a Visual Studio vb.net Windows Forms App and I a deploying it using ClickOnce Deployment.
Then I associated an own filetype with this app:

```
Project -> Properties -> Publish -> Options -> File Associations
```

[image]

When I publish the App and I create manualle a file e.g. Testfile.abc it gets the defined icon and by double clicking it opens my Application.

Question: How can I determine in my application, which file (e.g. c:\temp\Testfile.abc) started my App?
I read about command line parameters and that the first parameter is that filename, but here it is the filename of my App (*.exe).

Comment: If you're using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, read the second parameter (if the length of the resulting array is > 1, that is). The first is always the application executable path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1766013/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted correctly by Hans Passant the solution in [ClickOnce File Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759850/clickonce-file-association/1766013#1766013) works:

```
If Not (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments Is Nothing) Then
    ListBox1.DataSource = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
End If
```